# Structure of war file of html5 project

Tags: html, netbeans, ant, jboss, war

I have created with Netbeans a simple HMTL5 Project, and to try the html pages of this project I use the embedded Lightweight Server of Netbeans, that runs my pages on localhost, with port: 8383. But, if I want to create a .war from this project, to deploy it on a Jboss Application Server (for example, Jboss 7.1), how can I do this?

To create the war file I can use a specific target with build.xml file of Apache Ant, but what I need to know is the structure of the war file, in the case of a simple HTML5 Project.

My project contains simply:

```
--src/
----js/
----css/
----img/
--build.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

In a WAR file all the web content just sits at the root. You can use whatever folder structure you like, so for example files under js/ in your WAR file will be deployed under yourcontext/js/.

Comment: Okay, and to call these files from the browser, after having started the server and deployed the war, I have to use an url such this: localhost:8080/mycontext/index.html?